# Javascript multiplication results NaN when i press tab key on second value ( number with dot and comma ) Eg: 45,524.25 * 65,25,425.23

Tags: javascript

```
var price_prt=$row.find("input[name='PRQL_PRICE1[]']").val().replace(",","");

var qty_prt=$row.find("input[name='PRQL_QTY1[]']").val().replace(",","");

var prt_value= parseFloat(price_prt) * parseFloat(qty_prt);     

$row.find("input[name='PRQL_VALUE1[]']").attr('value',prt_value);
```

Comment: When i multiply comma has to remove. waiting for solution...

Comment: The problem is i have two comma in a numeric i want solution to remove two comma may in both values.

Comment: My code is working but when i click tab key from first input to second it result NaN

Answer (score 2):

You're only replacing the first comma, not all of them, you'll need a regex for that as parsing any number with a comma will result in `NaN`

```
var price_prt = $row.find("input[name='PRQL_PRICE1[]']").val().replace(/,/g,"");

var qty_prt   = $row.find("input[name='PRQL_QTY1[]']").val().replace(/,/g,"");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a84gwh4p/2/)

Comment: Hai this not working not removing first comma itself.

Comment: It's removing **all** commas, as that's what the replace does ?

Comment: 45,242,545.25 * 5 = 226212726.25 is result. this work when i enter first value when i go change second value i.e 5 by tab key result is NaN

Comment: And do you have this in an event handler, and what does that look like ?

Comment: @Ezhilarasan: You did something wrong. This answer is 100% correct (except the Fiddle is broken because it doesn't showcase the value with two commas)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - good catch on the fiddle, didn't notice i copied the same value in both inputs, fixed now